# Why am I getting a Segmentation error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
int entry,i;
printf("\nPlease indicate the number of records you want to enter :\n");
scanf("%d",entry);
char ent[entry][100000];
printf("\nPlease input records of students (enter a new line after each record), with following format first name last name score \n");
for(i=0;i<entry;i++)
    {
    gets(ent[i]);
    printf("%s",ent[i]);
    }
}
```

The following is a code to accept data of student , first name last name and then score.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &entry);`  You are missing the ampersand.

Comment: Also, most systems have a pretty low limit on the size of local arrays, you may be exceeding it. You should use `malloc()` instead.

Comment: @JS1 The error Persists even after taking care of the ampersand. Thanks though

Comment: Accepting an answer would be better if your issuee is solved.

Answer (score 2):

`main` should return `int`, not `void`.

```
int main(void) {
    /* ... */
}
```

---

```
scanf("%d",entry);
```

`scanf` expects the argument corresponding to the `"%d"` format specifier to be an `int *`. Your argument, however, is an `int`. Perhaps you meant this:

```
scanf("%d",&entry);
```

---

On that note, you should really check the return value of `scanf`. For all you know, the user didn't enter anything numeric.

```
if (scanf("%d", &entry) != 1) {
    exit(0);
}
```

---

In fact, this still allows the user to enter a negative number. Have you ever seen an array of a negative number of items? Seems strange to me, too... I think `size_t` would be a more appropriate type than `int` (and as a result, you'll need to use the `%zu` format specifier)...

Last but not least, `gets` is deprecated because it makes it impossible to prevent the user from overflowing buffers, which could cause segfaults.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    size_t entry;
    printf("\nPlease indicate the number of records you want to enter :\n");
    if (scanf("%zu",&entry) != 1)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    char ent[entry][100000];
    printf("\nPlease input records of students (enter a new line after each record), with following format first name last name score \n");
    for(size_t i=0; i<entry; i++)
    {
        fgets(ent[i], sizeof ent[i], stdin);
        printf("%s",ent[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you should use `int main()`instead of `void main`
2. when you use you should `scanf("%d",&entry)` instead of `scanf("%d",entry)`,what scanf need is an address.
3. you shouldn't use `gets()`,it's dangerous,try `fgets()`

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d",entry);     //scanf("%d",&entry)
char ent[entry][100000]; //error
```

you should use `malloc` to get an array when you can not know the length of an array in compiling time

Answer (score 0):

The error is in scanf use `scanf("%d",&entry)` instead of `scanf("%d",entry);`

Suggestion: use `int` as return type for `main`

Comment: Don't you want to add something about `gets()`?